# How to check if the predicate (second argument) is truthy on all elements of a collection (first argument)

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a freeCodeCamp challenge and the task is to check if the second argument is truthy on all elements of the first argument. Here is my code, it only works when the function should return false but not when it should return true.

```
function truthCheck(collection, pre) {
  for (let i=0; i<collection.length; i++) {
    if (collection[i] === pre) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

truthCheck([{"user": "Tinky-Winky", "sex": "male"}, {"user": "Dipsy", "sex": "male"}, {"user": "Laa-Laa", "sex": "female"}, {"user": "Po", "sex": "female"}], "sex");
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Do you want a function that returns `true` if all items inside the collection have the `sex` property? Or do you want a function that returns `true` is all item inside the collection have a particular value for the property `sex`?

Comment: should return true if all the items inside collection have the sex property

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like the following:

```
function truthCheck(collection, pre) {
  return collection.every(item => item[pre] !== undefined)
}
```

Comment: One could also use the double not (`!!`) as well:  `return collection.every(item => !!item[pre]);`

Comment: @Steve no because you want to check if the property exists, not if the property has a truthy value.

Comment: Interesting. I guess I was just going by what the OP said "check if the second argument is truthy"

Comment: Yep the question is not very clear about that.

Answer (score 0):

## Update

Understandong OP wants to match all objects as `true`. A second function is added: `checkAll()` which will match a given key. This is done by `.every()` and the keys are exposed by `Object.keys()`.

---

- The syntax is wrong for `truthCheck`.
- The second parameter `pre` isn't clear.

The input array `data` had been corrected. the second paeameter is now 2 strings: `key` (ex. `'sex'`) and `val` (ex. `'female'`)
`.filter()` will return the objects that are true.

```js
const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

const data = [{"user": "Tinky-Winky", "sex": "male"}, {"user": "Dipsy", "sex": "male"}, {"user": "Laa-Laa", "sex": "female"}, {"user": "Po", "sex": "female"}];

const check = (array, key, val) => 
  array.filter(obj => obj[key] === val);
 
log(check(data, 'sex', 'female'));

const checkAll = (array, key) => array.every(obj => 
  Object.keys(obj).includes(key));
  
log(checkAll(data, 'sex'));
```

Comment: Hi, he explicitly said that the function "should return true if all the items inside collection have the sex property", so I think that he don't want the second parameter like you wrote.

Comment: Updated, thanks.